# How to enable WebGL content inside QtQuick2 / QtWebKit within a QML application?

Tags: qt, webgl, qml, qtquick2

I'm doing some basic tests with a QML application to deliver WebGL content on desktop apps.
The basic test is the following code:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtWebKit 3.0;
 Rectangle {
   width: 800
   height: 600
   WebView { 
     url: "http://learningwebgl.com/lessons/lesson03/index.html"; 
     anchors.fill: parent 
   }
}
```

The window is shown and the HTML content appears but no WebGL content is shown.
I've tested it with other pages (like threejs examples). It seems that 3D content is somehow processed (at least I suppose it from my fan!), typical framerate display is shown (40 to 60 fps in many cases), but visually I can't see the WebGL content.

Do I miss something? Should I enable something else to support WebGL rendering inside the WebView?

I'm using Qt 5.4 on Windows 8 with VS Express 2013

Comment: It works in the web browser example that comes with Qt?

Comment: Very simple examples work quite fine in the web browser example app but with Very low framerate (about 10/15 fps). Example just a bit more advanded (with shaders and complex texturing) fail, sometime even crashing the app.

Comment: Why `WebView` and not `WebEngineView`? I 've tested these lessons with `WebEngineView` and it works nice with good FPS.

Comment: Thanks folibis. I've tried using WebEngineView in a QML only application, but the web page says that it doesn't support WebGL.
Then I've tried to make a Qt Quick application, where in the main.cpp I've written QtWebEngine::initialize(), but I get an unresolved symbol even if I set webengine in my .pro file and include <QtWebEngine/qtwebengineglobal.h>

Comment: PS: I tried the same page inside the Nano browser example, which uses WebEngineView and I still get that WebGL is anavaliable. What platform are you using? Could you share your code sample?

Comment: I should admit that I'm a little bit confused about Web GL support in Qt Quick. What is interesting is that Qt developers are finalizing [`QtCanvas 3D`](https://www.qtdeveloperdays.com/sites/default/files/presentation_pdf/PasiKer%C3%A4nen_Enabling%20Direct%20WebGL%20in%20Qt%20Quick%202.pdf) and are discussing on including (a custom version of) `three.js` to ease its usage. Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm quite confused too! :) Thanks for the news, anyway a raw WebGL support is preferable...